# PHPSESSID cookie - does it grant access to different websites on same server?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Here's a scenario that I'm wondering about. 
Let's say I have the following:

1. a php/apache web server running the following web sites:

   /var/www/version1ofmyapp/

   /var/www/version2ofmyapp/
2. cookies are enabled on user's machine.
3. web app writes data to the session upon log in/log out

Will logging in to version1ofmysite (and thereby creating a cookie called PHPSESSID) give me access to version2ofmysite? 
For example, I log in to version1 of the site and then I change the URL to version2, and it just lets me in as if I'm authenticated already. 
I would like to better understand why this is happening.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

Same domain

Comment: How are your domains setup? In other words do both versions share a common domain and only the subdomain changes, or are they completely different?

Comment: What are the actual URLs of the sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookies is defined for a domain and can be defined for a path. So you can limit the sending of a cookie.

If you have a sessionID which is used in two applications and use the same session-storage, you can access the informations which are saved in the session.

Therefore the information, that you are loggedin is used in both applications. You can change the name of the session (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to prevent that, or change the session-storage (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini file you can configure the server to allow this:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".mydomain.com"
```

That will allow subdomain access to the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie PHPSESSID is limited to the domain that created it and will only be sent to that domain or subdomain. If you have multiple domains on the same server you'll have a different PHPSESSID cookie for each.

If you use subdomains and you want to share session between them, you can use session_set_cookie_params($lifetime_in_seconds, '/', '.mydomain.com') before calling session_start() in order to share the same session across all the subdomains.

Scoping of cookies is by host name (misleadingly called domain), then name. You can have two cookies named PHPSESSID only if they are for different domains (hosts). A single domain cannot have two cookies that are named the same. If you try to do this, it is considered a change to the one that is already set.

Comment: what if I don't want to share the same session?

Comment: Then don't call php_set_cookie_params(). When start_session is called the domain will be set to the domain of whichever subdomain the session is being created by. Example subdomain1.mydomain.com, which means when the user goes to subdomain2.mydomain.com another cookie named PHPSESSID will be created for that domain. In each cookie the value will be a different session file on the server.

Comment: In other words each subdomain gets a different session and they will not be shared. This is the default behavior and you need to either use the php.ini method in the other answer or the call to session_set_cookie_params if you don't like the default behavior.

Comment: Erik it's actually not my code... but I grepped for php_set_cookie_params and its not being called.  if cookies are enabled, and I create a session variable, will php just create this cookie automatically?

Comment: I also checked for setcookie().  Also checked in *.js for anything with cookie. But i can't find anything.